# Is there any modern nodejs client for kafka in Kraft mode?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I want to use kafka in my nodejs application and only proper client library [kafkajs](https://kafka.js.org/) .
i have hosted kafka:3.6.0 in Raft mode using docker . The problem i am facing is kafkajs throws this error

```
KafkaJSNonRetriableError: The Kafka server does not support the requested API version
    at /Users/USERNAME/Documents/PROJECT/node_modules/.pnpm/kafkajs@2.2.4/node_modules/kafkajs/src/retry/index.js:55:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Kafkajs does not seems to work with kafka in Raft mode . Is there any other modern client for kafka for nodejs that support Raft mode ?